# Use AngularJs expression in meta tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meta

I use this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' ng-app="main" ng-controller="Main">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta ng-if="isAndroidWelcome()" name="viewport" content="width=900">
```

But the meta tag is always active, doesn't matter `isAndroidWelcome()` returns true or not.

Here is the main controller's code

```
var main = angular.module("main", ['ngDialog', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngCookies',
    'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'infinite-scroll',
    'ngTagsInput', 'tiksem-keyboard', 'ngSanitize' /*HTML_TEMPLATES_PLACEHOLDER*/]);
main.controller("Main", function($http, $element, $timeout, $scope, $locale, $location, $cookies){
    ControllerUtils.initController($scope, $location);

    var setLang = $scope.setLang = function(lang) {
        $scope.lang = lang;
        $scope.tr = TRANSLATION[lang] || TRANSLATION["en"];
    };
    //setLang($locale.id.split("-")[0]);
    setLang("ru");

    var onSignedInChanged = [];

    var isMobile = $scope.isMobile = Utilities.mobilecheck();
    var isAndroid = $scope.isAndroid = Utilities.isAndroid();
    $scope.isAndroidWelcome = function() {
        return $scope.getPath() == "welcome" && isAndroid;
    };
```

Comment: where is your root controller?

Comment: I've just added the code

Answer (score 0):

Here do something more like this:

```
<meta ng-change="isAndroidWelcome()" ng-model="viewport" content="width=900">
```

That way you can use an Angular controller for function isAndroidWelcome() on the ng-model you created (viewport).

Comment: Post your Angular controller, and we'll figure it out together.